# Is git add .; git commit -a equivalent to git add -A .; git commit -a?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am using Git version 1.9.1 and recently received this notice when making a commit on my repository:

> warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or
>   '--ignore-removal', whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with
>   respect to paths you removed.

I usually commit changes by using these two commands:

```
git add .
git commit -a
```

I am now wondering whether I should switch to using --ignore-removal or -A. I read some of the other StackOverflow answers about this warning message, but I'm still not entirely clear on whether there would be any difference which option I use given that I'm immediately following it with `git commit -a`, which stages files for removal anyway.

My goal is to just have git automatically recognize all changes to a directory - additions, modifications, and deletions, and in fact I have an alias set up to do this in one command. I am currently leaning toward changing my alias to this:

```
git add -A .; git commit -a
```

Would that achieve my goal? My tentative understanding is that `--ignore-removal` would only be relevant in the case where I deleted some files but am not ready to commit those deletions to git yet - is that correct?

---

Thinking about this a bit more, I'm realizing I may not need the -a option on the commit command if I'm using -A on the add command, so how about this?

```
git add -A .; git commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to just have git automatically recognize all changes to a
>   directory - additions, modifications, and deletions

Good sir, this is also my goal. I accomplish this by

```
git add -A
git commit
```

or

```
git add -A foo.bar
git commit
```

The first form will do as you say, it will add any and all changes. The second
form will only add changes to the specified file. I would add that `commit -a`
is not necessary with my way either, because everything has already been staged
with `git add`. I have been using this method for over a year now and it works
well for me.

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/f21b3920c87325f164ca1/misc/git-ac.sh)

Comment: Update: for my alias, I changed it to `git commit .` rather than just `git commit`, so that it will work from subdirectories too. That way I can commit only the files in a particular subdirectory if I want without getting a warning from git ("warning: The behavior of 'git add --all (or -A)' with no path argument from a
subdirectory of the tree will change in Git 2.0 and should not be used anymore" etc...).